# Codeigniter establish database outside of public_html

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter as a php framework

I need to write a script for a cron job outside of public_html that will modify a database, however I am not sure how to create a database instance where I can run queries and fetch the results

I tried looking for what requires I need and what classes to call, however I couldn't figure it out

Example:

you normally have to write

```
 $this->db->query("query");
```

however I need to run a query outside the scope of Codeigniter, outside the public_html folder. I need something like

```
require(database)
require(database_configs)
$DB = new $DB(configs)
$DB->query("query")
```

Comment: your question is not clear.what exactly do u wish to accomplish?what have you tried n what errors are you having?

Comment: possibly duplicates. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832284/how-can-i-connect-to-a-database-manually-in-codeigniter

Comment: If you need this outside the scope of codeigniter, then why do you need to use codeigniter code to handle this? you could just write regular php code with mysqli or PDO or whatever. If you need the config variable available, then just require the database config file and use the correct array for connection properties. Just be sure to define a `BASEPATH` constant prior to including the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application/config/database.php file for the following settings:

```
$active_group = 'default';  
$active_record = FALSE;
```

And now you can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) style. but `$this->db` also required. I don't know why you want avoid  CI db driver. It has large configuration such as query caching, profiling, optimization etc If you ignone CI Active record just set `$active_record = FALSE;`

Comment: Unless I read the question wrong, I don't think the issue is using active record. He wants a way to use the CI database settings **outside** of the scope of CI. So, without loading the CI bootstrap file, how does he use the CI db settings.

Comment: OK . OP can  create a model for connection management outside of the scope of CI. But I just suggest to use CI db driver

Answer (score 0):

yes you cant use codeigniter without loading CI. If you are looking at security issue of having cron job functions in public html, you can add more security by passing a hash code to the function from cron job url so even if someone tries to run the script he/she needs to have hash key.
Also you can check IP address to verify if script was run from the servers ip or outside.